# RN(0.61.4) when accessing with salesforce community api its coming as image/html it automatically showing Image in Android but not in ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, salesforce

React Native(0.61.4) when authenticating with salesforce api((servlet.filedownload?file=XXXXXXXX') its coming as image/html it automatically rerenders and showing Image in android but not in ios

this is the code i have implemented

```
<Image source={{
          uri: url, headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${decodeURIComponent(this.props.accessToken)}`
          }
        }} style ={{ width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    resizeMode: 'cover'}}
```

Comment: try to define width and height `style={{width: 50, height: 50}}`

Comment: already applied style but not resolved